# Iterative multiplication of the two lists in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply

I am trying to multiply the values stored in a list containing 1,000 values with another list containing  ages. Ultimately, I want to store 1,000 rows to a dataframe.
I wonder if it's better to use lapply fucntion or for loop function here.

`list 1`

```
  lambdaSamples1 <- lapply(
    floor(runif(numSamples, min = 1, max = nrow(mcmcMatrix))),
    function(x) mcmcMatrix[x, lambdas[[1]]])

*the out put is 1,000 different values in a list. *
```

`list 2`

ager1= 14:29

What I want to do is

```
  for (i in 1: numSamples) {
  assign(paste0("newRow1_", i), 1-exp(-lambdaSample1[[i]]*ager1))
   }
```

now I got 1,000 rows of values that I want to store in a predetermiend dataframe, outDf_1 (nrow=1000, ncol = ager1).

I tried

`

```
  for (i in 1:numSamples) {
    
    outDf_1[i,] <- newRow1_i
    
  }
```

I want to store newRow1_1, ,,,,,, , newRow1_1000 to each of the 1,000 row of outDf_1 dataframe.

SHould I approach different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this a bit. Many operations in R are vectorized so you shoudln't need `lapply` or `for` loops for this. You didn't give us any data to work with but the code below should do what you want in a more straightforward and fast way.

```r
lambdaSamples1 <- mcmcMatrix[sample(nrow(mcmcMatrix), numSamples, replace=T), 
                             lambdas[[1]]]
outDF_1 <- 1 - exp(-lambdaSamples1 %*% t(ager1))
```

Just note that this makes `outDF_1` a matrix, not a data frame.

To do this for multiple ages, you could use a loop to save your resulting matrices in a list:

```r
outDF <- list()
x <- 5
for (i in seq_len(x)) {
  lambdaSamples <- mcmcMatrix[sample(nrow(mcmcMatrix), numSamples, replace=T), 
                              lambdas[[1]]]
  outDF[[i]] <- 1 - exp(-lambdaSamples %*% t(ager[[i]]))
}
```

Here, `ager1`, ..., `agerx` are expected to be stored in a list (`ager`).

Comment: thanks for your answer! it really helped! if I want to make multiple matrices (outDf_1,, outDf_x) with iterative lambdaSamples (lambaSamples1,,, lambdaSamples x) and iterative age lists (ager1,,,,agerx), should I make a loop ?

Comment: @HyolimKang Yes, I edited my answer to include a possible approach.